# Error items - 90046 Xcode

Tags: xcode, app-store-connect, archive

Anyone have this error, ITMS-90046?

[image]

Comment: What did you do to get that error?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

***Apple Developer Program Support***

technical notes and troubleshooting steps for this kind of issue:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2415/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40016427-CH1-INTRODUCTION-EXAMPLE_ERRORS

and "Checking Distribution Entitlements”:
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/qa/qa1798/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40014167

and this one as I can see that there is something about the Bundle in the error message which you are receiving:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/Bundle.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008195-CH4-SW1

You may also check:
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/ConfiguringYourApp/ConfiguringYourApp.html

Answer (score 1):

In the Apple Developer Center in the App IDs section check if you activated the `Associated Domains` capabilities for your Bundle

[image: associted domains]

If yes and you do not need it disable it and regenerate your App Store mobileprovision.

If you really need that feature you need to setup the associated domains within your app. More information on [Apple Doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/AddingCapabilities/AddingCapabilities.html)